# Combobox selectedValue binding a class 's property not update

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

```
public class Rma
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
}
```

and this property:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty ActRmaProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ActRma", typeof(Rma), typeof(MainWindow),new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public Rma ActRma
    {
        get { return (Rma)GetValue(ActRmaProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActRmaProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged("ActRma"); }
    }
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsByIdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsById", typeof(ObservableCollection<int>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
public ObservableCollection<int> ItemsById
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<int>)GetValue(ItemsByIdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsByIdProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged("ItemsById"); }
    }
```

and the combobox in xaml:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsById}" DisplayMemberPath="Id"
     SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding ActRma.Id , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
                                          Margin="3"
                                          AlternationCount="1"/>
```

thewhen I change via code behind the value of Id the copmbobox not show the value .
e.g:

```
ItemsById = new ItemById();
ItemsById.Add(1);
ItemsById.Add(2);
ActRma.Id = 2;
```

Comment: Try setting `SelectedValue="{Binding ActRma.Id , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"` to `SelectedValue="{Binding ` **ActRma** `, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: not works not Update the value.

Comment: Now use the work around, just use in code behind the follow line when make a new value of id.
I know this is not elegant form ,but in this case works

 ComboBoxRmaid.SelectedValue = ActRma.Id;

Comment: Can you see 1 and 2 displayed in the `ComboBox`? It seems that you are using this in the code behind. Make sure that you have correct `DataContext` set in you `UserControl`. What can you see in the Output Window?

Comment: if I use your suggestion I see nothing in combobox

Comment: I fixed my point with this : public class Rma: INotifyPropertyChanged { public int Id { get { return Id; } set { Id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); } } public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); } }

Comment: Your `ComboBox` is still referring to property named `Id` which doesn't exists on type `int`. Please see [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) about what `DisplayMemberPath` does.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your example you are using `DependencyProperty` for your items in your `Window`. `ComboBox` is designed to work with collections so let's use it in `MvvM` (Model-View-ViewModel).
ViewModel.cs:

```
private List<int> _cmbList;

public List<int> CmbList//this is the collection that we will use to hold values
{
    get { return _cmbList; }
    set { _cmbList = value; OnPropertyChanged("CmbList"); }
}
//with additional property
private int _ActRma;

public int ActRma
{
    get { return _ActRma; }
    set { _ActRma = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ActRma)); }// In here you can handle the changed value of your ComboBox. No need for event handler in this case as setter is called everytime you change selected item in UI.
}
```

Your view model is then referenced in your MainWindow.xaml:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VM;assembly=VM"
```

This then should be setting the `DataContext` of your MainWindow.xaml like so:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

At this point your window and all of the elements declared in it will inherit the DataContext object which is our ViewModel.
Then to use the Collection in our ComboBox you can use it like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CmbItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding ActRmaId}" AlternationCount="1"/><!-- here we hold the Id of the selected item, we don't need to set the Display path as we are binding to the int and this being primitive type doesn't have any properties! -->
```

Comment: I fixed my point with this : public class Rma: INotifyPropertyChanged { public int Id { get { return Id; } set { Id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); } } public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); } }

Answer (score 0):

To expand on XAMlMAX's answer- unless you've set your datacontext to itself in the codebehind, you'll need to do in the xaml itself- define x:name and use ElementName in the binding definition-

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsById,ElementName=_this}"...
```